# How can I install AMD R9 270X driver to Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, 16.10, amd-graphics

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm having hard time trying to install AMD R9 270X drivers.

AMDGPUPRO is not supported for R9 270X. 16.10 doesn't have fglrx. I'm basically stuck.

When I check Additional Drivers, I see this:

```
Unknown:Unknown
This device is using an alternate driver.
Using processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs from amd64-microcode (proprietary)
Do not use the device
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If the *amdgpu* driver does not support your card, you will have to use the open source *radeon* driver on 16.10.

If you want to use *fglrx*, you need to install Ubuntu 14.04 (not 14.04.5 though), to be able to use the older Catalyst drivers.

Comment: How can I check if it is supported or not? Is there any terminal commands or such?